# How to draw different images on each side of SCNPlane Geometry

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

My ultimate goal is to have an SCNNode representing an image floating in space. This is more or less easily accomplished with the current code I have below, but the problem is that the back side of the image isn't rendered and is thus transparent from the back. I want to be able to display a different image on the back so that there is something to see from both sides. the `isDoubleSided` property doesn't work here because it simply mimics what's on the front. Any Ideas? I looked into the idea of creating my own geometry from Sources and Elements but it seemed very complex for what should be really simple.

My current code:

```
private func createNode() -> SCNNode{
    let scaleFactor = image.size.width/0.2
    let width = image.size.width/scaleFactor
    let height = image.size.height/scaleFactor

    let geometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = image
    geometry.materials = [material]

    return SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Im working on an AR project too! Can you please show in your example code how you declare the image variable?

Comment: @user287474 Check out my github and then let me know if you have any more questions! https://github.com/aivantg/ar-invaders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want different images, you need to use different materials. SceneKit allows specifying material per geometry element. `SCNPlane` has only one element, that's why `isDoubleSided` just mirrors image on the back side. You have two options here:

- Create two `SCNPlane` geometries, orient them back to back and assign different images to each `geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents`
- Create custom `SCNGeometry` from `SCNGeometrySource` (4 vertices of plane) and two `SCNGeometryElements` (one for each side: 2 triangles, 6 indices), and assign array of two materials (different images) to geometry.

The first option is easier, but looks more like a workaround.

Comment: So would that first option entail just adding a child node and putting it right behind the first plane?

Comment: Tried it once I got to a computer and it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Another option is to use an SCNBox with a very small z value, then map the "front" and "back" planes of the box, which appear to be element 0 (front) and element 2 (back) of the material array. `boxGeometry.materials = [frontMat, baseMat, backMat, baseMat, baseMat, baseMat]`